# How close do you need to be to a Poké-Stop?

Tags: pokemon-go

How close do you need to be to a Poké-Stop to spin the Photo Disc and reap its rewards?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to have the PokéStop or Gym inside your "action circle" -- the pulsing circle that will sometimes spawn. This circle's radius at its widest point is 40 meters, so you must be within 40 meters of the building you want to interact with. This radius is set to the same as Ingress'.

When a building is eligible, you'll notice that Pokéstops will "expand" out, and the action circle will leave a trace mark on the ground.

Comment: I have confirmed this using google maps. Apart from cases where the GPS glitches, and *thinks* you are somewhere else, the maximum distance is exactly 40m.

Comment: I have seen a bug sometimes where I am close enough to trigger the animation of the Gym/PokeStop as if I got in range, but when I tap on it it claims I'm too far away.

Comment: So basically, the same as [tag:ingress]?

Answer (score 6):

When walking you see a purple circle around your avatar, if the pokestop is inside that circle you can activate it.

Comment: How far is that in meters, approximately?

Comment: While not entirely sure, I think it's approximately 25 meters

Comment: The exact measurement is 40m.